# How to move from one level to another in Google Actions Trivia game?

Tags: actions-on-google

I've made Google Action using Trivia template. Try it by saying

> Ok Google, Talk to LCDP Trivia Challenge

In this, once you finish playing one level, the template asks whether you want to play same level again or not. Instead, I want user to try a new level.(Suppose a user is done playing easy level, then instead of playing the easy level again, I would like to ask whether they want to play Medium or Hard level)

At this moment, the template only allows the user to play same user again and again. But I think if the user has scored well in one quiz they would like to try the next level.

So, how can I suggest different difficulty once the game is completed instead of choosing Yes/No for playing same level again? Can I customize this trivia template?

[image: Screenshot of the LCDP Trivia game]

Answer (score 0):

The resolution of the screenshot isn't very good, I can't read what's written there.

There is no way to further customize the template. If you would want more flexibility, you would need to implement your own action.

All customizations are listed in the list of [configuration parameters](https://developers.google.com/assistant/templates/trivia#configuration_parameters) in the documentation.